# Is there any way to apply gradient color to text using velocity js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, velocity.js

Is there any way to apply gradient color to text using velocity js?
I have checked https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

But my requirment is that I need to add gradient using js dynamically where gradient part will change gradually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [forcefeeding](http://velocityjs.org/#forcefeeding) for the start and end values. Make sure the strings are identical apart from the changing values (ie, if it ends on a three step gradient then make sure it begins on a three step gradient).

Since version 1.4 Velocity has supported string and colour animation when forcefeeding, however the documentation hasn't caught up.